# SQL Server : convert column as Header with values in other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am joining 3 tables, `Category, Value, NewFill`:

```
SELECT 
    SaricasaNewFill.value AS 'Selected Values',
    SaricasaCategory.description AS 'Category' 
FROM 
    dbo.SaricasaValue 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.SaricasaNewFill ON SaricasaValue.value = SaricasaNewFill.value 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.SaricasaCategory ON SaricasaValue.cat_id = SaricasaCategory.cat_id
```

This is the result:

[image: And this is the result]

Now I have created a dynamic pivot when I can make the `SaricasaCategory.description as 'Category'` as my column header. But I do have a problem displaying multiple values. The query I created just display's that last value the `SaricasaNewFill.value as 'Selected Values'`

Here is the result of my pivot:

[image: Here is the result of my pivot query]

This is the query I wrote:

```
DECLARE @cols AS varchar(max), @qry AS varchar(max);

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(c.description)
                      FROM dbo.SaricasaValue v 
                      INNER JOIN dbo.SaricasaNewFill n  ON v.value = n.value 
                      INNER JOIN dbo.SaricasaCategory c  ON v.cat_id = c.cat_id
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')

SET @qry = 'SELECT ' + @cols + 'FROM (SELECT n.value, c.description 
                                      FROM dbo.SaricasaValue v 
                                      INNER JOIN dbo.SaricasaNewFill n ON v.value = n.value 
                                      INNER JOIN dbo.SaricasaCategory c ON v.cat_id = c.cat_id) x 
            PIVOT
                (MIN(value) FOR description IN (' + @cols + ')) p'

  EXECUTE(@qry)
```

Is something missing is my query? I hope someone helps! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you need to show output in comma separated value.

```
DECLARE @cols as varchar(max), @qry as varchar(max);

select @cols = stuff  ((select DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(c.description)
      FROM dbo.SaricasaValue v INNER JOIN dbo.SaricasaNewFill n  ON v.value = n.value 
  INNER JOIN dbo.SaricasaCategory c  ON v.cat_id = c.cat_id
  for XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','varchar(max)'),1,1,'')

  SELECT  n.value ,c.description into #saricasa
  FROM dbo.SaricasaValue v INNER JOIN dbo.SaricasaNewFill n  ON v.value = n.value 
  INNER JOIN dbo.SaricasaCategory c  ON v.cat_id = c.cat_id

  set @qry = 'select ' + @cols + 'from(SELECT  description,stuff  ((select DISTINCT '','' + c.value
  FROM  #saricasa c where d.description=c.description
  for XML PATH(''''), TYPE).value(''.'',''varchar(max)''),1,1,'''') as value
  from #saricasa d
) x 
  pivot
  (min(value) for description in (' + @cols + ')) p'

  EXECUTE(@qry)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you change varchar(max) to nvarchar(max)
prevent Unicode problem,And your 'from' should add space ' from'

```
    DECLARE @cols as nvarchar(max), @qry as nvarchar(max);

select @cols = stuff  ((select DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(c.description)
      FROM dbo.SaricasaValue v INNER JOIN dbo.SaricasaNewFill n  ON v.value = n.value 
  INNER JOIN dbo.SaricasaCategory c  ON v.cat_id = c.cat_id
  for XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','varchar(max)'),1,1,'')

  set @qry = N'select ' + @cols + N' from(SELECT  n.value ,c.description 
  FROM dbo.SaricasaValue v INNER JOIN dbo.SaricasaNewFill n  ON v.value = n.value 
  INNER JOIN dbo.SaricasaCategory c  ON v.cat_id = c.cat_id
) x 
  pivot
  (min(value) for description in (' + @cols + N')) p'

  EXECUTE(@qry)
```